# Sum of values in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sum

my code:

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT units,finalgrade FROM grades WHERE course='BSN' &&     semester='1-1' && studentnumber='$username'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
  {

  $aw=array($row['units']*$row['finalgrade']);

  }
```

this outputs:
5.25, 6, 6.75, 6, 5.25, 6.75, 4.5

how can i get the sum of those numbers?

Comment: sum them up in the same loop?

Comment: `$sum = 0;` before the loop, then `$sum += $aw;` inside the loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this entirely in SQL with this query:

```
SELECT SUM(units * finalgrade) AS thesum FROM grades WHERE ....
```

There will be exactly one row returned, and you can read the result with `$row['thesum']`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in two ways

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT sum(units*finalgrade) as units FROM grades WHERE course='BSN' &&     semester='1-1' && studentnumber='$username'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
  {

  $aw=array($row['units']);

  }
```

or

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT units,finalgrade FROM grades WHERE course='BSN' &&     semester='1-1' && studentnumber='$username'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
  {

  $aw +=array($row['units']*$row['finalgrade']);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do it using SQL,if you need only sum there is not need to get all data to client.
So the answer of Jon makes sense for you.

Answer (score 0):

for an indivisual student with studentNO=5

```
SELECT studentNO, SUM(units * finalgrade) AS thesum 
FROM grades 
WHERE studentNO =5;

studenNO thesum
5          500
```

For all students

```
SELECT studenNO, SUM(units * finalgrade) AS thesum 
FROM grades
group by studentNO ;

studenNO thesum
5          500
6          510
7          480
```

Answer (score -1):

Use array_sum:

```
$sum = array_sum($aw)
```

Comment: Why did I get down-voted for? The person specifically asked "how can i get the sum of those numbers?" which were in the array $aw.